# Bash: echoing variable with spaces overlapping string

Tags: bash

I'm looking for a particular line in a variable, e.g.

```
echo "$CodeDesc"

0x19 ERASE(6)
0x1A MODE SENSE(6)
0x1B START STOP UNIT
0x1C RECEIVE DIAGNOSTIC RESULTS
0x1D SEND DIAGNOSTIC
0x1E PREVENT ALLOW MEDIUM REMOVAL
0x23 READ FORMAT CAPACITIES
0x24 SET WINDOW
```

e.g. if I was just looking for "MODE SENSE(6)", I'm using grep and awk (also tried with sed)

```
desc="$( grep "0x1A" <<< "$CodeDesc" | awk '{print substr($0, index($0,$2))}' )"
```

This does give me the correct string, i.e. "MODE SENSE(6)" but when I echo it overlaps some of the string:

```
echo "DESC: \"$desc\""
```

Gives me:

```
  "SC:"MODE SENSE(6)
```

Notice the \" has moved to the beginning and DE is missing.

Later on I'm also printing the same variable along with another variable:

```
echo -e "${desc}${code}"
```

I would expect this to print:

```
MORE SENSE(6) 0x1A 1
```

But instead I get:

```
 0x1a 1NSE(6)
```

I can't figure out what's going on with this, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you've got a CR without a LF in there.

Comment: Where do you get the string from? If it is from a file, it may have strange characters. To "clean" it, you can do `dos2unix`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently your `$CodeDesc` is a string made of lines terminated by CRLF. `grep` and `awk` faithfully preserve the line ending, and the shell's `$()` substitution strips off the final LF leaving you with a string that just ends with a CR.

When the CR is printed, the cursor moves to the beginning of the line and whatever gets printed next overwrites what was there.

You can fix this by adding a `| tr -d '\015'` to your pipeline, or you could do it all in `awk` including the `grep` part:

```
desc="$(awk '{gsub(/\r/,"")} /0x1A/ {print substr($0, index($0,$2))}' <<< "$CodeDesc")"
```

Comment: It looks even weirder than that -- it looks to me like there's a carriage return, then a space, then the (normal) linefeed. Removing the CR may or may not fully solve the issue. Also, Brian would do well to find out where these garbage characters are coming from in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, the | tr -d '\015 sorted the problem.

@Gordon, I'm initially doing a wget to get the codes/descriptions and I filter out just the code and description

Answer (score 3):

No awks and greps are needed here.

Bash version > v4:

```
declare -A codes

while read -r code desc; do
    codes["$code"]=$desc
done <<< "$CodeDesc"

printf 'DESC: "%s"' "${codes['0x1A']}"
```

Bash version < v4:

```
while read -r code desc; do
    [[ $code = '0x1A' ]] && printf 'DESC: "%s"' "$desc"
done <<< "$CodeDesc"
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Gilad, I hadn't thought of doing a map, the above solution solved my specific issue so accepted that as the answer

Comment: Very good answer. If I were the author of the question, I would accept your reply